# How to retrieve and access multidimensional array in java for android application

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

At present i am working on multidimensional array in java.
My requirement is:
A multidimensional array is stored in parse like

1.How to retrieve this array from parse, and how to store in a variable?

2.How can i get the values like:

> [["ram","1","10"],["def","2","20"]]
>
> item names=ram,def
>       item quantity=1,2
>       item prices=30

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just use json?

Comment: Hi Scary Wombat, i really didn't have knowledge with json. can u give me the example for that?

Comment: plenty of examples if you google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
JSONArray var=objects.get(0).getJSONArray("itemDetails");
Log.d(TAG_NAME,"object itemDetails:"+var);
Log.d(TAG_NAME,"length of var is"+var.length());
Log.d(TAG_NAME,"1st element:"+var.get(0));
for (int i=0;i<var.length();i++){
JSONArray dynamicArray=(JSONArray)var.get(i);
for (int j=0;j<dynamicArray.length();j++){
    if(j==0){
        itemNames=itemNames+dynamicArray.get(j).toString();
        if (i<var.length()-1){
            itemNames = itemNames + ",";
        }
    }else if (j==1){
        itemsQuantity=itemsQuantity+Integer.parseInt((String) dynamicArray.get(j));
    }else if (j==2){
        itemsPrice=itemsPrice+Double.parseDouble((String) dynamicArray.get(j));
    }
}
}
```